# wxpython multi panel to swith solutions?

Tags: wxpython

changepanel0.py
  """
  four different file,named changpanel0.py changepanel1.py changepanel2.py changepanel3.py
  """

```
import wx
from changepanel1 import PanelOne
class My_App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = My_Frame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

class My_Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,None,-1,"My Frame",size = (280, 500))    
    self.panel1 = PanelOne(self) 
    self.panel1.Show()
    self.plst = []

    print self.plst

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = My_App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

changepanel1.py

```
import wx
from changepanel2 import PanelTwo

class PanelOne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        basicLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "panel 1",pos=(80,150))
        next = wx.Button(self,-1,"Next",pos=(50,200))
        back = wx.Button(self,-1,"Back",pos=(150,200))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnNext,next)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnBack,back)

    def OnNext(self,event):
        self.Hide()
        self.GetParent().plst.append(self)
        tmp = PanelTwo(self.GetParent())
        tmp.Fit()
        tmp.Show()
        print self.GetParent().plst

    def OnBack(self,event):
        tmp = self.GetParent().plst.pop()
        tmp.Fit()
        tmp.Show()
        self.Destroy()
```

changepanel2.py

```
import wx
from changepanel3 import PanelThree

class PanelTwo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        basicLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "panel 2",pos=(80,150))
        next = wx.Button(self,-1,"Next",pos=(50,200))
        back = wx.Button(self,-1,"Back",pos=(150,200))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnNext,next)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnBack,back)

    def OnNext(self,event):
        self.Hide()
        self.GetParent().plst.append(self)
        tmp = PanelThree(self.GetParent())
        tmp.Fit()
        tmp.Show()
        print self.GetParent().plst

    def OnBack(self,event):
        tmp = self.GetParent().plst.pop()
        tmp.Fit()
        tmp.Show()

        print self.GetParent().plst
        self.Destroy()
```

changepanel3.py

```
import wx
class PanelThree(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

        basicLabel = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "panel 3",pos=(80,150))
        next = wx.Button(self,-1,"Next",pos=(50,200))
        back = wx.Button(self,-1,"Back",pos=(150,200))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnNext,next)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnBack,back)

    def OnNext(self,event):
        self.Close()

    def OnBack(self,event):
        tmp = self.GetParent().plst.pop()
        tmp.Fit()
        tmp.Show()

        print self.GetParent().plst
        self.Destroy()
```

hello , I want to swith multi panels , so i use a list to maintain，are there other solutons to do the same job?

Comment: Your title and question includes the word "swith". Did you mean "switch"?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) on the subject a while back that you might find helpful. Otherwise, check out the various notebook-like controls, like Notebook or ChoiceBook, Treebook, etc. I [wrote](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/12/03/the-book-controls-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/) about those too.

EDIT (03/19/2012): Put your different panel code into differently named files, like panelOne.py, panelTwo.py, etc. Then in your main application, you just import them:

```
import panelOne
import panelTwo
```

Then you'd just instantiate them. Something like

```
myPanel = panelOne.PanelName(parent)
```

I already mentioned one method of switching panels sequentially.

Comment: I have read it , but if there are more than two panel , like six or seven , how to swith between them ?

Comment: If there's more than two, then use a Notebook. Or show a popup dialog with the list. Or if you want to switch them sequentially, then keep a list of panels and an integer to do the switching.

Comment: yes , i want to swith them sequentially , and i want to put different panel in different filename, so how to do that ? can you show me an example ?